# How to use external .c files with CGO?

Tags: c, import, go, cgo

To write some C code in a comment above `import "C"` is straightforward:

```
// foo.go
package main

/*
int fortytwo() {
    return 42;
}
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("forty-two == %d\n", C.fortytwo())
    fmt.Printf("forty-three == %d\n", C.fortythree())
}
```

And it works fine:

```
$ go install
$ foo
forty-two == 42
```

However, C code in it's own .c file:

```
// foo.c
int fortythree() {
  return 43;
}
```

...referenced from Go:

```
// foo.go
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("forty-two == %d\n", C.fortytwo())
    fmt.Printf("forty-three == %d\n", C.fortythree())
}
```

...does not work:

```
$ go install
# foo
could not determine kind of name for C.fortythree
```

Comment: How to build this code with go build instead of go install?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C header file foo.h is missing:

```
// foo.h
int fortythree();
```

Reference the header file from Go like this:

```
// foo.go
package main

/*
#include "foo.h"

int fortytwo() {
    return 42;
}
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("forty-two == %d\n", C.fortytwo())
    fmt.Printf("forty-three == %d\n", C.fortythree())
}
```

Behold, the power of foo.h:

```
$ go install
$ foo
forty-two == 42
forty-three == 43
```